# NameError: name 'sim_functions' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

`cli.py` calls upon `method()` in `gri.py`.

`gri.py` needs to call upon `consolidate()` in `sim_functions.py`.

---

**cli.py:**

```
from sim_functions import *
from gri import *

method()
```

**gri.py:**

```
#from sim_functions import *
from sim_functions import consolidate

def method():
    programmatic_dict = sim_functions.consolidate()  # Fails
```

**sim_functions.py:**

```
import multiprocessing.dummy as mp
import multiprocessing

def consolidate_programmatic(multiple):
    ...

    return programmatic_dict
```

---

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cli.py", line 178, in <module>
    cli()
  File "/home/me/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/data-simulator-vZW8uMY6-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1137, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/data-simulator-vZW8uMY6-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1062, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/me/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/data-simulator-vZW8uMY6-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/me/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/data-simulator-vZW8uMY6-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 763, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "cli.py", line 43, in cli
    main_gri()
  File "/home/me/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/data-simulator-vZW8uMY6-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1137, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/data-simulator-vZW8uMY6-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1062, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/me/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/data-simulator-vZW8uMY6-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/me/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/data-simulator-vZW8uMY6-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 763, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "cli.py", line 159, in main_gri
    gri_dict = consolidate(multiple_per_tag, emissions, effluents_waste, non_discrimination, customer_health_safety, esg)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator/src/gri.py", line 26, in consolidate
    programmatic_dict = sim_functions.consolidate_programmatic(multiple_per_tag)
NameError: name 'sim_functions' is not defined
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I can add to post to help further clarify.

Comment: As you used wildcard imports, in `cli.py` you should replace `gri.method()` by `method()` and in `gri.py` you should replace `sim_functions.consolidate()` by `consolidate()`

Comment: Why are you importing `sim_functions` into both scripts and import the one into the other? `consolidate` is not a function in `sim_functions` (but `consolidate_programmatic` is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did an opsie.

You only need to call upon the `<name>.function()` if it belongs to an OOP Class.

In my case, no functions belong to any classes, so just `function()` suffices.

Comment: Note: I have to wait 48HRS unit I can accept answer